# How to use font awesome lumos icons theme

Tags: node.js, font-awesome

**I dont know how I can use Lumos icon theme in my node website. I can use icons but the icons use the nox for light theme and my web site is dark. How i can use light icons for dark theme website with font awesome?**

Icon Code:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

[Lumos theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7xXC.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much 'bout Font awesome utilities but i typed **text-light** in the class attribute "forcing" Lumos style

Your example:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

Lumos:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars text-light"></i>
```